# Integrating trustpilot unique link feature for customer with php and curl

Tags: php, curl, trustpilot

My need is to generate unique link for the customers of Trustpilot widget.For that, I need to have an access token.I tried all possible ways but facing same error

{“reason”:“Unknown grant_type”} "

Below is my code for the same

```
$data = array(
GRANT_TYPE => GRANT_TYPE_VALUE,
TRUSTPILOT_USERNAME => TRUSTPILOT_USERNAME_VALUE,
TRUSTPILOT_PASSWORD => TRUSTPILOT_PASSWORD_VALUE,
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,“https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken”);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
‘Authorization: Basic base64 encoded apikey:secretkey’,
‘Content-Type: application/json’
));
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, but I had to do a few things to get it working.

The payload data had to be transformed using `http_build_query` like so

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
  'grant_type' => 'password',
  'username' => $email,
  'password' => $password,
));
```

Then curl had problems with verifying SSL certificate from the server. So I added these two lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

The headers value where changed into

```
$authorization = 'Basic '. base64_encode($key . ':' . $secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: ' . $authorization,
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 ));
```

---

The final code snippet:

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
'grant_type' => 'password',
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
));
$authorization = 'Basic '. base64_encode($key . ':' . $secret);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: ' . $authorization,
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 ));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: http_build_query should only be called once.... if you remove one of the two calls, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Yes I tried with application/x-www-form-urlencoded but result is same

Comment: When I added it, I started getting `"reason": "Authentication Failed"`